# How to keep track of the state in functional component in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I revealed all the drop-down list from the nav items on hover instead of click by creating a separate state variable for all the three different NavDropDown and it worked. Is there any other shortcuts and alternatives beside that?

Currently my code is as follows:

```js
function Navigation(){
  const [isOpenAbout, setIsOpenAbout] = useState(false);
  const [isOpenServices, setIsOpenServices] = useState(false);
  const [isOpenContact, setIsOpenContact] = useState(false);
  return (
   <Nav className="ml-auto">
    <NavDropdown
      title="About"
      onMouseEnter = { () => setIsOpenAbout(true) }
      onMouseLeave = { () => setIsOpenAbout(false) }
      show={ isOpenAbout }
    >
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/1.1">Who we are</NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/2.2">
        How we work
      </NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/2.2">
        Certifications
      </NavDropdown.Item>
    </NavDropdown>

    <NavDropdown
      title="Services"
      onMouseEnter = { () => setIsOpenServices(true) }
      onMouseLeave = { () => setIsOpenServices(false) }
      show={ isOpenServices }
    >
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/2.1">
        Cloud Digital Transformation
      </NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/2.2">
        Expert Cloud Advise and Support
      </NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/2.3">
        Software Development
      </NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/2.4">
        Dedicated Teams
      </NavDropdown.Item>
    </NavDropdown>
    <Nav.Link href="https://www.genesecloud.academy/" target="_blank">
      Cloud Academy
    </Nav.Link>
    <NavDropdown
      title="Contact"
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsOpenContact(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsOpenContact(false)}
      show={isOpenContact}
    >
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#sales">Sales</NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#support">Support</NavDropdown.Item>
    </NavDropdown>
  </Nav>

  )
}
```

What's the best possible way to keep the track of the state? It would have been better if anyone could assist me out.

Comment: Looks good, if you only need the state in this file use hooks, if you want to do it in another way you can use css/jss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<Navigation />` component you could setup a property called, `activeDropdown`. On `onMouseEnter` you could set the state of the title of the `<NavDropdown />` like you already are and clear `activeDropdown` on `onMouseLeave`. Lastly in your `show` prop you can compare the title to the `activeDropdown`:

```
function Navigation(){
  const [activeDropdown, setActiveDropdown] = useState("");

  const clearActiveDropdown () => setActiveDropdown("");
  ...
  <Nav className="ml-auto">
    <NavDropdown
      title="About"
      onMouseEnter={ () => setActiveDropdown("about") }
      onMouseLeave={ clearActiveDropdown }
      show={ activeDropdown === "about" }
    >
      ...
    </NavDropdown>
  </Nav>
  ...
}
```

Comment: Great to hear. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your code by using only 1 state object, this is more general and easier to extend in the future:

```js
function Navigation(){

  const defaultState = {
    about: false,
    services: false,
    contact: false
  };

  const show = function (dropdownElement) {
    const newState = Object.assign(this.dropdownState);
    newState[dropdownElement] = true;
    setDropdownState(newState);
  };

  const hide = function(dropdownElement) {
    const newState = Object.assign(this.dropdownState);
    newState[dropdownElement] = false;
    setDropdownState(newState);
  }

  const [dropdownState, setDropdownState] = useState(defaultState);

  return (
   <Nav className="ml-auto">
    <NavDropdown
      title="About"
      onMouseEnter = { () => show("about") }
      onMouseLeave = { () => hide("about") }
      show={ this.dropdownState.about }
    >
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/1.1">Who we are</NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/2.2">
        How we work
      </NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/2.2">
        Certifications
      </NavDropdown.Item>
    </NavDropdown>

    <NavDropdown
      title="Services"
      onMouseEnter = { () => show("services") }
      onMouseLeave = { () => hide("services") }
      show={ this.dropdownState.services }
    >
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/2.1">
        Cloud Digital Transformation
      </NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/2.2">
        Expert Cloud Advise and Support
      </NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/2.3">
        Software Development
      </NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/2.4">
        Dedicated Teams
      </NavDropdown.Item>
    </NavDropdown>
    <Nav.Link href="https://www.genesecloud.academy/" target="_blank">
      Cloud Academy
    </Nav.Link>
    <NavDropdown
      title="Contact"
      onMouseEnter={() => show("contact")}
      onMouseLeave={() => hide("contact")}
      show={ this.dropdownState.contact }
    >
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#sales">Sales</NavDropdown.Item>
      <NavDropdown.Item href="#support">Support</NavDropdown.Item>
    </NavDropdown>
  </Nav>
  )
}
```

Comment: Even the dropdown items didn't come when I hover over the nav items with these changes.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: I didn't receive any exceptions beforehand but the dropdown list in the nav bar are not shown even on hover or on click. But, on this revised code why are you adding 'this'? 'this' is used to bind the function in class based component that's why it's not detecting and throwing TypeError: Cannot read property 'dropdownState' of undefined.